# Loop through multiple vectors, calculate area for each, output CSV

Tags: qgis, area

I have 20 vector shapefiles in QGIS.

I want to calculate the area for each one without doing it the manual way.

Is there a way I can loop through each one, and output a CSV of each vectors area?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Search for "field calculator" in processing toolbox and run it as Batch process:

[image]

Choose a method to load all your files:

[image]

Enter a fieldname like `my_area`, adjust the fieldtype if needed to a numerical one, enter a calculation method, either `$area` or `area($geometry)` as formula and set your outputfolder and filetype.

To easily fill all layers with your settings you can click on *Autofill* and then choose *Fill down*.

Then run it.

*Hint: instead of "field calculator" you can also run "Refactor Fields", which allows to calculate multiple fields at once. Its disadvantage is, that you need to set the original fields one by one if they are not identical in all layers.*